# C function modification

Tags: c, oop

I had some fun with imitating OOP in C, but I got somewhat discouraged when I understood that I'll have to call member methods like `obj->method(obj, ...)`. Then I thought about cloning and modifying functions at runtime. Can I implement a function like strdup but for functions using a simple parser to identify the return opcode to stop copying and then modify a value in the function to point to the object the member method refers to so that I can use just `obj->method(...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, at least from what it sounds like you are asking, which is to modify functions at run-time. Modifying functions at run-time is possible but is difficult and requires considerable knowledge (and is system-specific). However, you seem to be asking to be able to execute a function and modify the function so that it does something with the object it is associated with. However, by the time the function is executing, there is generally no information about that object available: In a call like `obj->method(…)`, there is generally no reference to `obj` included in the arguments. So even if you could modify the function at run-time, it does not have the information needed to do the job you want.

There are ways to do it at compile-time. That is how C++ developed. If that is a feature you want, the best approach is to use C++.